# How to trigger Dialogflow ES intent when incoming message is atachment not a text

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have incoming message from Viber bot as attachment (location share) with no text in Dialogflow ES, so I'd like to trigger intent based on that message. Incoming request is like:

```
        "payload": {
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "payload": {
                        "long": ##.####,
                        "address": "xxxxxxxx",
                        "lat": ##.#####
                    },
                    "type": "location"
                }
            ],
            "source": "viber",
            "body": {
                "sender": {
                    "language": "en-GB",
                    "api_version": 10,
                    "country": "xx",
                    "id": "xxxxxx",
                    "name": "xxxx xxxx"
                },
                "silent": false,
                "event": "message",
                "message_token": xxxx,
                "chat_hostname": "xxxxx",
                "message": {
                    "location": {
                        "lat": ##.#####,
                        "lon": ##.#####
                    },
                    "type": "location"
                },
                "timestamp": xxxxx
            },
            "contact": {
                "channelId": xxxx,
                "cId": "########",
                "contactId": #######
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to trigger Dialogflow intent, because there are no words I can use as training phrases

Answer (score 0):

I find an easy solution to this:

I only added "location" in events box and Dialogflow accept trigger the intent without any text in the message or training phrases to be marked

But I'm not sure what exactly triggers:

`"type": "location"`

or

```
"message": {
      "location": {...
```

Any way it works.